# Newspaper article scraper in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create a Scrapy spider to work through a list of URLs of newspaper articles (mostly pages like [this](http://www.xinhuanet.com/fortune/2019-12/12/c_1125338715.htm) with a few anomalous ones in the mix). I want to collect the article text and the publication date. Here is the spider code:

```
class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AS"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('newdata.txt') as g:
            urls = g.readlines()

        # urls = [
        #     'http://www.xinhuanet.com/fortune/2019-12/12/c_1125338715.htm',
        #     'http://www.xinhuanet.com/2019-12/10/c_1125330924.htm',
        #     'http://www.xinhuanet.com/legal/2019-12/08/c_1125322172.htm',
        # ]
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        divs = response.xpath('//div')

        paras = []
        for p in divs.xpath('.//p'):
            a = p.get().replace("<p>", "").replace("</p>", "").lstrip()
            paras.append(a)
        b = ''.join(paras)
        divs2 = response.css("div.h-info")
        try:
            for date in divs2.css("span.h-time::text"):
                c = date.get()
                c = c.strip()
                yield {
                    'date': c,
                    'text': b,
                }

        except UnboundLocalError:
            d = "NO_DATE_FOUND"
            yield {
                'date': d,
                'text': b,
            }
```

How can I deal with the fact that some of the article pages don't have a date on them, or have it in a different place, and so 'c' comes up blank? I get the 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment'...

What would be the best way to store this collected data? Could I use the 'JsonLinesItemExporter' to produce a .json file with the yield contents for each url as a separate line? Or alternatively, is there a way to use feed item exporter to produce a separate text document for each article.

Huge thanks again for any help anybody can offer. I'm fairly new to Python and Scrapy and quickly get in over my head.

Comment: Why don't you use `try` `except` block?

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding this, but am not sure what kind of exception is raised? The scraper still actually works anyway - any suggestions how to efficiently store this yield in a file? Is JsonLinesItemExporter the best way to go?

Comment: @Piron thanks for your help with this and my other issues. I think I figured this one out, putting it as UnboundLocalError and setting the variable as d = "NO_DATE_FOUND" seems to work okay (as in the edits above)